# Liquibase removes semicolons

Tags: sql, database, migration, liquibase

I have a liquibase changelog file with some insert statements which I have done with  tags but somehow when I generate a SQL file from the changelog (for a SQL Server database) it removes the semicolons at the end of the statements. In my changelog file it looks like this:

```
<changeSet author="Ferid (generated)" id="1528876614155-371-MSSQL-58">
   <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onSqlOutput="TEST">
      <dbms type="mssql" />
   </preConditions>
   <sql>
        BEGIN TRAN;
        INSERT INTO pdc_matrix (pattern_id, prod_ins_level, mai_class_id, result_id, y_or_r, and_level) 
        values (1012, 'I', 41, (select res_id FROM result_def where mai_id = 41 and res_name='MAI_MPO'),0,1);
        INSERT INTO pdc_matrix (pattern_id, prod_ins_level, mai_class_id, result_id, y_or_r, and_level) 
        values (1012, 'A', 51, (select res_id FROM result_def where mai_id = 51 and res_name='MAI_OPE'),0,2);
        INSERT INTO pdc_matrix (pattern_id, prod_ins_level, mai_class_id, result_id, y_or_r, and_level) 
        values (1012, 'A', 52, (select res_id FROM result_def where mai_id = 52 and res_name='MAI_OPR'),0,3);
        commit;
   </sql>
   <rollback/>
</changeSet>
```

but the SQL file generated from it looks like this:

```
-- Changeset C:/Users/Ferid/Documents/Box Sync/PRIVATE_Ferid/liquibase-3.5.5-bin/sdk/workspace/changelog/com/example/newChangelogModInserts.xml::1528876614155-371-MSSQL-58::Ferid (generated)
BEGIN TRAN
GO

INSERT INTO pdc_matrix (pattern_id, prod_ins_level, mai_class_id, result_id, y_or_r, and_level) 
values (1012, 'I', 41, (select res_id FROM result_def where mai_id = 41 and res_name='MAI_MPO'),0,1)
GO

INSERT INTO pdc_matrix (pattern_id, prod_ins_level, mai_class_id, result_id, y_or_r, and_level) 
values (1012, 'A', 51, (select res_id FROM result_def where mai_id = 51 and res_name='MAI_OPE'),0,2)
GO

INSERT INTO pdc_matrix (pattern_id, prod_ins_level, mai_class_id, result_id, y_or_r, and_level) 
values (1012, 'A', 52, (select res_id FROM result_def where mai_id = 52 and res_name='MAI_OPR'),0,3)
GO
commit
GO
```

Why does this happen and what can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it out, I just had to add `splitStatements="false"` in the `<sql>` tag and it didnt format the SQL statements at all:

```
<changeSet author="Ferid (generated)" id="1528876614155-371-MSSQL-58">
   <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onSqlOutput="TEST">
      <dbms type="mssql" />
   </preConditions>
   <sql splitStatements="false">
    BEGIN TRAN;
    INSERT INTO pdc_matrix (pattern_id, prod_ins_level, mai_class_id, result_id, y_or_r, and_level) 
    values (1012, 'I', 41, (select res_id FROM result_def where mai_id = 41 and res_name='MAI_MPO'),0,1);
    INSERT INTO pdc_matrix (pattern_id, prod_ins_level, mai_class_id, result_id, y_or_r, and_level) 
    values (1012, 'A', 51, (select res_id FROM result_def where mai_id = 51 and res_name='MAI_OPE'),0,2);
    INSERT INTO pdc_matrix (pattern_id, prod_ins_level, mai_class_id, result_id, y_or_r, and_level) 
    values (1012, 'A', 52, (select res_id FROM result_def where mai_id = 52 and res_name='MAI_OPR'),0,3);
    commit;
   </sql>
   <rollback/>
</changeSet>
```